# string variable as haskell command

Tags: haskell

when I do following it works

```
print [1..5]
```

and result [1,2,3,4,5]

but why following is not working

```
let x = "[1..5]"
print x
```

I want to process a string variable as haskell command. can someone please help me in it.

Answer (score 2):

Note that your second example:

```
let x = "[1..5]"
print x
```

works just fine, it just says something different than you intended.

If you wish to consider some string as a valid Haskell expression then you'll need to *interpret* that string via some Haskell interpreter.  The most common interpreter is accessed via the ghc-api.  A clean wrapper for the ghc-api is the `hint` package.

A simple example of using hint is (via ghci):

```
import Language.Haskell.Interpreter
let x = "[1..5]"
Right result <- runInterpreter $ setImports ["Prelude"] >> eval x
print result
```

The above code will:

1. Import an Interpreter module from the `hint` package
2. Set a string, `x`, which is the expression you desire to evaluate
3. Run the interpreter on the expression
4. Print the result (which is already a string, so you might prefer `putStrLn result`).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get a list as a string, take advantage of the show function

```
let x = show [1..5]
print x
```

Your first answer "works" because function application is right associative, so Haskell evaluates [1..5] to produce the list [1,2,3,4,5] and passes this to the print function.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for `System.Eval.Haskell.eval` or one of its variants. In this case, I believe that

```
import System.Eval.Haskell
do x <- eval "[1..5]" [] :: IO (Maybe Int List)
   putStrLn (if isJust x then "" else show $ fromJust x)
```

will do what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've been unable to get Haskell actually working. I see nothing wrong in this, but if it causes some problem, I'd be glad to know about it instead of just being told to test it.